# mailchimp segments & groups

Tags: mailchimp, mailing-list

In Mailchimp is I click on a user I can see which group they belong to under the details tab but I can't see which segment they belong to.  Is there a way to check which segment they are in?

Also is their a difference between *customer groups* & *groups*?

As some users are in a *customer group (i.e. General, Wholesale, Retailer, Not Logged In)* which are not in the list of *groups* we created under manage list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check what segment someone is in based on their profile. Segments are what you create to organize your subscribers. You can create segments based on group criteria to keep track of what user is in what segment, but you can't directly see each segment a subscriber is in. A subscriber can be in an infinite number of segments, and some segments can even be created on the fly when setting up a campaign.

I'm not sure I can answer the second part of the question. I don't think *customer groups* is something native to Mailchimp. Perhaps it's a merge tag you created? These would be used in signup forms and in the body of your emails.